# wiredep `devDependencies: true` not copying files

Tags: gulp, wiredep

When using wiredep in gulp to inject files into index.html, setting `devDependencies: true` does not copy files listed in the bower.json `"devDependencies":{...}` block over to my build/vendor folder. The file references are injected into index.html, but files are not copied over.

[Gulpfile.js]

```
...
return gulp.src(config.buildDir + 'index.html')
  .pipe($.wiredep.stream({
    devDependencies: true,
    ...
```

[bower.json]

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.4.*",
  "morris.js": "^0.5.0"  
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
  },
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Although `wiredep` was injecting the proper file refs into the html page, the `mainBowerFiles` plugin (which is responsible for moving the files) needed to know to to target devDependencies too.

Passing `{includeDev: true}` to the `mainBowerFiles` constructor did the trick. [MainBowerFiles docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#includedev)

`...
return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles({includeDev: true}),
...`